# How to fix ')',<column constraint>,<type name>or comma expected,got '1'

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio

i created table and this is my problem .. any one can help me ?

and this massage appear

```java
 ')',<column constraint>,<type name>or comma expected,got '1'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfQQx.png  "my android studio code"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKfFS.png  "my problem massage"

```java
final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
               QuestionTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
               QuestionTable._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + "TEXT" +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT " +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT " +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT " +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION4 + " TEXT " +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + "INTEGER" +
               ")";
```

Comment: try this [link](https://pastebin.com/TmjAFvvh) you need some spaces... also a `;`

Comment: same problem https://i.imgur.com/6JcD6Gy.png

Comment: you are missing a few `,` .. see updated [link](https://pastebin.com/TmjAFvvh)

Comment: You claim that after fixing the spaces and commas you still have problem. Edit the question and show the "fixed" version, so we can see (in text, not as image) what you've done to fix it. --- Also, please print the value of `SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE` and show it. We don't know what all those constants are, so maybe there's an error there too. Show us the result, i.e. what the SQL database sees, then we can better help identify the issue.

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573608/column-constraint-or-comma-expected-got-text-sqlite-database-err

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some spaces and a few commas

```
final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
               QuestionTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
               QuestionTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT ," +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT ," +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT ," +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_OPTION4 + " TEXT ," +
               QuestionTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER" +
               ");";
```